# Django - Fiter the latest objects based on DateTimeField

Tags: django, django-models, django-urls

I have a model class with two `DateTimeField`:

```
class Map(Models.Model):
    date_created = models.DateTimeField('date created', auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField('date updated', auto_now=True)
```

I would like to have a query that returns the latest Map created and another query that returns the latest updated.

Comment: Did you do any research? Did you try anything? Did you check the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/)? Show your effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`latest()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#latest):

> `latest(field_name=None)`
>
> Returns the latest object in the table, by date, using the field_name
>   provided as the date field.

```
Map.objects.latest('date_created')
Map.objects.latest('date_updated')
```

Comment: @BelowtheRadar simplified the answer, check if it is what you need please.

Answer (score 2):

Check the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/)

```
Map.objects.order_by('date_created').first(10)
```